How to design a neural network where input consist of binary bits and output has discrete amplitudes?
The array size of input and output are different (e.g.: 88 - 176).    Order of data points are matter it should not change.  Also i want to    make sure the reversibility like when i give amplitudes(176) as an    input it should give me back binary bits(88).  as it is sequential data i am considering RNN but not sure about reversibility.
